# are those boundary $ C^1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am studying PDE and my question is that if we have a open unit disk with  $ [0,1)$ on x axis removed, is the boundary of this set $C^1$ ? And on the other hand, is the boundary of a open rectangle $C^1$ ? I am really confused about this.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recalling the definition: A boundary is $C^k$ if it can be expressed locally as a $C^k$ curve. 
However, since both boundaries have edges, they are only continuous and therefore not $C^1$.

Comment: does that mean that $B(0,1)$ which has $C^1$ boundary?